# Video decoder configure

Tags: android

I am writing a app which decodes video samples and plays decodes samples. For this i am using MediaExtractor API. While configuring decoder i am getting error. Here is my log

```
01-08 11:46:50.225: E/ACodec(23085): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -2147483648
01-08 11:46:50.225: A/MediaCodec(23085): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaCodec.cpp:743 CHECK_EQ( mState,INITIALIZED) failed: 3 vs. 2
01-08 11:46:50.225: A/libc(23085): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 23136 (MediaCodec_loop)
01-08 11:46:50.225: I/OMXClient(23085): Using client-side OMX mux.
01-08 11:46:50.225: E/ACodec(23085): Unable to instantiate a decoder for type 'video/avc'.
01-08 11:46:50.225: A/ACodec(23085): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:3302 CHECK(mCodec->mNode != NULL) failed.
01-08 11:46:50.225: A/libc(23085): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 23137 (CodecLooper)
```

And here is my code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < videoExtractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
                    MediaFormat format = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
                    String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
                    if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                        videoExtractor.selectTrack(i);
                        videoExtractorForSeek.selectTrack(i);
                        videoDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
//error is in below line
                        videoDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
                        break;            
                    }
                }
```

This code working in android version 4.2 and above. and failing in 4.1.2

Comment: Hey, did you get any answer for this ? I am having the same issue is guess. I am using the ExoPlayer by google and this crash seems to come on an 4.1.2 Samsung Galaxy Core. It works completely fine on other devices.